# How to run a Chrome webapp while disabling everything else?

Tags: google-chrome, web-application

I've used the "create webapp" option in order for me to have a shortcut for running Plex on Chrome without loading everything else. However, it seems to still be loading extensions such as Lastpass, uBlock Origin etc.

How do I disable this behavior? Passing --disable-extensions doesn't seem to do it (I can still see them) and kiosk mode is not what I'm looking for, as I'd like to retain the Windows buttons closing, maximizing and minimizing.

Thank you!

Edit: optimal behavior would be being able to choose which extensions to load, as some of Plex's plugins are delivered via Chrome Extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Chrome allow to have [multiple profiles](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en), even it has a [Guest mode](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6130773?hl=en).

Each profile have it's own settings including the extensions that are installed on each profile. You might have one profile for with all the extensions that you need and another a free of extensions.

When creating a new profile, Chrome will ask you if you want to create a shortcut.

Another option is to use different browsers, i.e. you might use two different Google Chrome release channels (see [Chrome Release Channels](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel/))

Please note that having a shortcut that opens a profile not having extensions installed, or one that has few extensions, don't requiere to modify the corresponding shortcuts to include arguments. You could even set that profile to automatically delete the browsing history on exit. From [Clear, allow, and manage cookies in Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?hl=en) (bold and inline images not included)

> **Delete cookies after you close Chrome**
>
> You can let sites remember information during your browsing session, but automatically delete the cookies when you close Chrome.
>
> 1. On your computer, open Google Chrome.
> 2. At the top right, click More More and then Settings.
> 3. Click Privacy and security and then Cookies and other site data.
> 4. Turn on Clear cookies and site data when you close all windows.
>
>    - If you're synced to Chrome, sync will pause when you quit your Chrome browsing session.

Comment: This potentially could be a better answer, it would only need to provide the required arguments to add to the shortcut. Nevertheless, I don't use this setup anymore, so I won't be able to test it.

Comment: @FabioFreitas If you have a dedicated shortcut to open profile having no extensions, there is no need to include arguments in the shortcut... adding this to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could run Chrome in Incognito mode, where extensions are by default disabled.

To run in that mode, use the Chrome switch of
[--incognito](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#incognito).

Comment: I'll use that for now, but it's suboptimal as I do have some extensions (e.g. uBlock Origin) active in incognito.